# Why shouldn't a certificate's Common Name be used for identification?

Tags: certificates

I understand that using a Subject Alternative Name is to be used for identification, and using Common Name has been deprecated under RFC 2818.

I'm trying to understand the logic behind that decision. Why shouldn't a certificate's Common Name be used for identification?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/IGT2fLJrAeo) it's because the usage of Common Name is ambiguous, while Subject Alternative Name is unambiguous. Due to the ambiguity of its usage, checking it is more complicated and has resulted in security bugs in the past.